# Are there any shortcuts are available in Ubuntu like open a window or some built-in applications?

Tags: keyboard

Instead of using mouse every time, are there any shortcuts are available in Ubuntu? If yes, can anyone provide me with a list?

Answer (score 2):

Hold the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (the windows/mac logo) to get a list (provided you are in a recent enough version of Ubuntu)

Or in System Settings -> Keyboard you can set your own/edit current shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Hold your super key (windows button) for a while then a list of short cuts will appear before you.

for instance, if you press any number with windows key it is same as clicking any icon on the launcher.

> Windows+1